# Parse fails to send push notifications. Why?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I cannot understand why my App fails to receive Push notifications and when I run the error report it says I fail to initialize parse before calling the parse library. I cannot figure out what I should do. Please Help.

**Source**

```
import com.parse.*;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.PushService;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String un, pw;
    public TextView username;
    public EditText pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Parse.initialize(this, "QmmXYAxVVSoT7MGlE3ZcAseCoLehfZko3BZJbo1P",
                "SQHTLKcpNKDCLZWTgfOOFPEcmFYkdmWywKNProWG");
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
        PushService.startServiceIfRequired(this);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        PushService.subscribe(this, "push", MainActivity.class);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editloginusername);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpass);

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                un = username.getText().toString();
                pw = pass.getText().toString();

                ParseUser.logInInBackground(un, pw, new LogInCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            new CallMainPage().execute();

                        } else {
                            // username.setText("");
                            pass.setText("");
                            makeToast("User name or password not recognized.");

                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });

        Button signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new CallSignup().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class CallSignup extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Signup.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            return "";
        }
    }

    public class CallMainPage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainPage.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            return "";
        }
    }

    public void makeToast(String text) {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should probably remove your private keys from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve your problem? If not, you can follow the [official tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications). The most part of the setting up process is made in the Application class.

Maybe that was the problem, you were calling the **Parse.initialize**, **setDefaultPushCallback** and soon in your MainActivity, not in the Application class.